# Google Form validation from a Google Sheet for Inventory

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to make an inventory system and am struggling with using a Google form to check out inventory. I would like the form to validate that the products being removed from inventory are actually present in the inventory in a Google sheet. I've tried getting AI to write a script to accomplish this, but I can't seem to get it working. It still allows me to submit whatever I want in the text box for inventory removal. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

So to sum that up, can you use a column from a Google sheet for validating entries in Google form text box?

I'll include one version of the generated scripts. I've tried well over a dozen iterations, but hopefully this will provide some idea of what I've been working with.

```
function validateCaseNumbers(caseNumbers) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Serialized Case Numbers');
  
  if (!dataSheet) {
    throw new Error("Unable to access the 'Serialized Case Numbers' sheet.");
  }
  
  var existingCaseNumbers = dataSheet.getRange('E:E').getValues().flat().filter(String); // Assuming case numbers are in column E
  
  return caseNumbers.every(function(caseNumber) {
    return existingCaseNumbers.includes(caseNumber);
  });
}

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  
  var caseNumberResponse = itemResponses.find(function(response) {
    return response.getItem().getTitle() === 'Case Numbers'; // Replace 'Case Numbers' with the title of your case number question in the form
  });

  if (!caseNumberResponse) {
    // Case numbers response not found, prevent form submission
    throw new Error("Case numbers response not found in form submission.");
  }

  var caseNumbers = caseNumberResponse.getResponse().split(',');

  if (!validateCaseNumbers(caseNumbers)) {
    // Display error message
    var errorText = "One or more of the entered case numbers are invalid or were not checked in. Please enter valid case numbers.";
    var validation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
      .requireTextContainsPattern('.+')
     

 .setHelpText(errorText)
      .build();
    caseNumberResponse.withItemResponse(caseNumberResponse.getResponse().setValidation(validation));
    throw new Error(errorText);   } }
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the tags **before** posting your question. You are asking an off-topic question. See [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> ..., can you use a column from a Google sheet for validating entries in Google form text box?

The short answer is no.

One option is to run a script to update the form data validation.